# Webform ReportViewer Service Unavailable, timeouts and performance issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

We are currently using ReportViewer control embedded in an aspx file to render RDLC files for an MVC Web Application. The data is fetched from an SQL Server using nhibernate, the ReportViewer is running in Local Processing mode. The various reports contain calculations within the RDLC including sums, counts and grouping.

We are finding the reports using this method run terribly slowly, usually causing the web server to display the Service 'Unavailable Error'.

It appears that the live servers do not have enough resources to run these reports, and even in an environment where the servers have much more memory and CPU speed, while the reports do not time out, they take a very long time to render even a single report.

Does anyone have recommendations on this matter. How can we reduce the amount of processing time for these reports?

From observing the resource usage, the calculations carried out internally by report viewer on the data are taking a great deal of time. As an example of the data we are looking at about 3000 individual reports, using over 40000 records to calculate from.

Comment: Try background workers and caching

Comment: So background worker is usable in ASP.NET? Would Spinning off a thread and processing the fetching of data reduce the load on the server? I'm guessing it wouldn't be usable within the ReportViewer though.